# Overlapping div with fixed positioned

Tags: css, html, overlap

I have difficulties finding the issues here.

Here's my CSS:

```
.band1{
    background-image: url(http://edward.firstcom.com.sg/corporate/Tarkus%20Interiors/tarkushome.jpg);       
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        background-position:center bottom;
        background-size:cover;
        padding:10% 0% 100% 0%;
        margin-bottom:50px;
        z-index:100;
}

.band2{
    background:#000;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    color:#fff;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    z-index:50;
    text-align:center;
}

.band3{
    background:#6F0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:-1;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="band1">
</div>

<div class="band2">
BLACK
</div>

<div class="band3">
GREEN
</div>
```

So the idea is that when I scroll down, the BLACK bar will come out like it's been there whole the time. It means the way it shows the words from bottom to top (not top to bottom like usual way when we scroll pages).

Afterwards, when I scroll down again, the GREEN bar will come out the same way the BLACK bar came out.

I have been playing around with the z-index to make them overlapping with each other. However, when I scrolled, the GREEN bar come out, but the BLACK bar somehow messed up.

Please help.
And do sorry for my broken explanation and messy code.

This is the Jfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2E5W3/

Thanks a lot. And pls do give me explanation for I am not very expert in this.

Comment: So the problem is, the black bar starts out already showing? or do you want the green bar to overlap the black bar?

Comment: Yes.. I want it to be like this: when I scroll, Black bar's showed first.. and when i scroll down further, the green bar appears.

Comment: Ok, so the black bar should not be showing up until you scroll? And then when once you scroll again, the green bar should come up and the black one should be gone?

Comment: Yes... I wanna have that unique scrolling effect thingy. It should be like showed up from bottom to top like (perhaps) what you've seen in Jfiddle for the green bar.